# Magento: Special Price not Visible in Product Information

Tags: magento-1.6, magento

I am using Magento 1.6.1.0 and would like to use the special_price attribute (which is enabled for 'All Product Types'). Like so:

[image: magento special price attribute]

However the special price field, which I have seen visible on countless screen shots from other systems, is not visible. Here's a screen shot of my 'prices' tab in the product information editor:

[image]

What have I missed here? As you can see from the screen shot, the Tier Price is showing (and working) completely fine. Do I need to enable the special price attribute elsewhere?

Comment: Perhaps it was moved to another group in the attribute set?

Comment: Special Price is under the attribute Default->Prices->special_price. My product is using the 'Default' attribute set. Should that be correct?

Comment: maybe you need to re-index and flush the cache

Comment: What is the Admin label for `special_price`? Perchance was it changed to Price 1, Price 2 or Price 3?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I've tried re-indexing and deleting everything in the /var/cache folder. Still not working. The Admin label is set to 'Special Price'

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what else it could be? Could any of my files be corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, as i see you have attribute value set as `required`, but i dont see any red asterisk symbol (*) near to it. and actually i dont see on screenshot `Special Price` field either??
so all you need is:

1. create attribute.
2. name it `Special Price` with code `special_price`.
3. set to `Display on product page`.
4. Add it to your `Attribute Set`.
5. edit product and enter `Special Price` value.
6. then call it on product view.

there is no magic. i dont see what you have done exactly. But it looks like you did something wrong.

ps. **by the way isnt it default Magento feature?? Special Price with dates From/To??**
have you modified your core features somehow??

Comment: Yes I suspect that the core features had been messed with as there are other developers working on this project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I found a fix that worked for me. Under the attributes list, I searched "price" found an existing "special price" attribute. I had to edit the "apply to" section to in my case "all product types" but would also work for any particular product type. Hope this helps someone else.